# Извлечение программы из Windows

Tags: windows

У меня появился интерес создать установщик Paint. Все уже, наверное, знают, что в новом обновлении Windows 10 его удалят и закинут в магазин.

Вопрос: какие файлы связаны с mspaint.exe, чтобы я, создавая установщик, закинул туда файлы и установил на новую винду 10 обычный paint, который пока еще присутствует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместе с программой необходимо устанавливать все библиотеки, которые она использует. Какие именно — можно посмотреть с помощью программы [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить на экранном снимке выше, `mspaint` на моей Windows 7 SP1 x64 требует следующие библиотеки:

- `ADVAPI32.DLL`,
- `KERNEL32.DLL`,
- `GDI32.DLL`,
- `USER32.DLL`,
- `MFC42U.DLL`,
- `MSVCRT.DLL`,
- `COMDLG32.DLL`,
- `OLE32.DLL`,
- `OLEAUT32.DLL`,
- `SHELL32.DLL`,
- `NTDLL.DLL`,
- `COMCTL32.DLL`,
- `SHLWAPI.DLL`,
- `PROPSYS.DLL`,
- `RPCRT4.DLL`,
- `WINMM.DLL`,
- `VERSION.DLL`,
- `GDIPLUS.DLL`.

Посмотрите, какие из них отсутствуют на Windows 10 и обеспечьте их наличие.

Comment: Да вроде бы всё так сделал. Создал папку , закинул туда все библиотеки а также mspaint.exe. При запуске этого mspaint получаю ошибку unable to create a new document. Я так понимаю не хватает еще чего-то?

Comment: @m1zl-s, запустите [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Добавьте в диалог, открывшийся при запуске программы, фильтр `<Process Name> <is> mspaint.exe <then Include>` (задайте параметры в верхней строчке, затем нажмите последовательно `Add` и `Ok`). После этого запустите Paint, добейтесь ошибки и вернитесь в ProcMon. Найдите в конце списка строку, где ячейка `Operation` равна `CreateFile`, а `Result` **не** равна `SUCCESS` — это и есть источник ошибки. В ячейке `Detail` будет указан путь до файла, на открытии которого paint упал.

Comment: Сделал всё так. Там этих CreateFile  где Result!=success было очень много, всё добавил. Всё равно та же ошибка.

Comment: Также я исправил все ошибки, но все равно, paint не запускается , та же ошибка.

Comment: вы мне поможете?

Comment: @m1zl-s, вы запускаете `mspaint` напрямую или через ярлык? На сайте Microsoft [пишут](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/ms-paint-windows7-unable-to-create-new-document/9499806f-5a8e-4d39-b5cb-caa56763a78c), что в ярлыках возможно появление «лишних» свойств.

Comment: @m1zl-s, ещё [есть предположение](https://windowsforum.com/threads/please-help.180013/#post-588112), что дело в отсутствующем файле локализации (`путь_до_mspaint/en-US/mspaint.exe.mui`).

Comment: ну я сделал так как надо . Создал папку в Program Files(x86) поместил туда mspaint.exe.СОздал в этой папке папку en-US. закинул туда из system32 mspaint.exe.mui. СОздал ярлык на рабочем столе. И все равно ошибка не удалось создать новый документ.

Comment: я попробовал сделать так взял Windows 7 из нее достал из папок System32 и SysWOW64 два файла mspaint.exe и mspaint.exe.mui.

Comment: в своих папках поудалял. И закинул эти все равно та же ошибка.